# launch .sh from desktop half work....

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, .desktop

I have a .sh script Call mainSc.sh which look like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
{
cd /home/myrepository
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/myrepository/build/src/
./myscript.sh | python mypythonscript.py
} || {
notify-send "it didn't work..."
}
```

And my problem is when I launch it from terminal (./mainSc.sh ) it work fine and when I try to launch it from the .desktop I created, it launch and work until ./myscript.sh and my python script does not work... 
I really don't understand why....

thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to MayeulC I found an alternative :

launching in a terminal, my command in my .desktop is now :

```
gnome-terminal -e /home/myrepository/myscript.sh
```

in this way I can monitor the execution of all codes and solve problem in an easier way !

I discovered that my python script was not execute by the same version of python when I was launching it by the .desktop or from terminal (but I don't know why yet).

I'll work on it !
Thanks

Dd

Answer (score 1):

This behavior can be explaned easily if you are dealing with the standard input in `myscript.sh` (waiting for user input, for example). As no terminal is attached, your script terminates, just like `cat` would do, for instance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I open and attached a terminal to this process to resolved that ? if yes, how ?

Comment: The best way to do it would be to change the script `myscript.sh` itself. There is really no point in running a command line program within a graphical environment if it requires some textual interactions. Depending on what `myscript` does, however, you could use a GUI to communicate with it, send it a default command when launching the script, or, more complex, feed it an open [named pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) that you close afterwards. But really, modifying `myscript.sh` is the best solution here, if you can afford it.

Comment: myscript.sh launch a code (in c++) which just make online video analysis (detect event), as far I know there is no input, only output. this output I want to send it to the python script I did. Which get the "online" information from the first code and  count the number of event and then write on serial port. ...

Comment: You could probably try to use screen if that's an option for you: `screen -t "mainSc" 2 bash -c '/my/script.sh'` (or just write your entire script between those quotes). I am not sure if `bash -c` is necessary here.

Comment: I did know screen, I will have a look it could be a solution. I've found that I had some problem with python execution.